# What is the easiest way to find the maximum of $9\cos(t) - 8\cos(3t)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What is the easiest way to find the maximum of $9\cos(t) - 8\cos (3t)$?

Comment: The standard first derivative test worked for me. You may want to look up the triple angle formulas if you get stuck. If you know some complex variables, you can derive these fairly easily with DeMoivre's formula and Euler's formula

Answer (score 2):

Express $\cos(3t)$ in terms of $\cos(t)$ and differentiate with respect to $t$ or $\cos(t)$.